# Discrepancy between SQLite's strftime / julianday and Cocoa's timeIntervalSince1970?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, sqlite, nsdate, strftime

```
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
 [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
 NSDate *date1 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"1213-02-27"];
 NSTimeInterval nsdateResult = [date1 timeIntervalSince1970];
 NSTimeInterval sqliteResult = -23883638400;
 GHAssertEquals(sqliteResult, nsdateResult, @"sqlite and nsdate should agree");
```

The expected number is what SQLite tells me should be the result, but this test fails since Cocoa tells me -23883033600 instead of -23883638400...i.e. 4 days later!
What gives? Am I doing something wrong or is either SQLite or Cocoa wrong?

***Edit***

Just checked the math and it seems Cocoa is giving me a wrong value: according to [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=days%20between%202/27/1213%20and%201/1/1970), there are 276431 days between 2/27/1213 and 1/1/1970. Take this times 24*60*60, and you get the value given by SQLite... so am I doing something wrong or is this some kind of Cocoa bug?

***Edit 2***
Fvu is right, it has to do with the Gregorian/Julian craziness back in 1582.

```
NSDate *date1 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"1582-10-15"];
NSDate *date2 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"1582-10-14"];
NSTimeInterval i = [date2 timeIntervalSinceDate:date1];
```

Surprisingly, i is 777600, i.e. 10/14 is 9 days LATER than 10/15 because it automatically is viewed as a Julian date whereas 10/15 is viewed as a Gregorian date. So basically what I will need to do is convert any dates before 10/15 from the Julian to the Gregorian calendar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sample date predates the [Gregorian calendar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar) so I think some oddities can be expected.  However, as at the introduction of the Gregorian calendar the date advanced by 10 days I don't have a bulletproof explanation for the calculated 4 day difference.

Comment: hm but see docs for nsdate: "NSDate models the change from the Julian to the Gregorian calendar in October 1582" http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Yeah I read that.  That means imo that Apple believes (or hopes? :-)) that their implementation is correct.

Comment: btw the reason it's 4 not 10 days is that the Julian calendar had its leap years wrong...hence the change to Gregorian in the first place...